# My computer doesn't start unless I reset the jumper in CMOS

Tags: boot

I just put this computer together yesterday, and I finally had to go to bed last night. The computer only boots when it the clear CMOS jumper is set to clear. This is really strange. I have tried to isolate the problem.

Comment: How many hard drives? IDE or SATA?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide more detail. Have you checked the CMOS battery is OK and seated in the holder properly?

Comment: Duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/709985/pc-wont-start-unless-i-reset-cmos/1198434#1198434

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this question is very vague and some may suggest to vague for this site; the reasons are nearly endless so I'll give you a few thoughts and suggestions.

This sounds like the battery is dead or nearly dead on the motherboard! The CMOS is not able to store the information for the BIOS. When you reset it, it has enough charge to tell the BIOS it's been reset, therefore use default values. Next time round, it cannot access the information.

Also, make sure the fan speeds are not on variable but all are set to constant.

It could be a power issue (IE, fautling PSU) although unlikey IMO.

Lastly, you have a faulty motherboard. Change the board over.

[Source](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/pc-will-not-post-or-boot-without-clearing-cmos-daily.28609/)